# Calculate pressure increase due to heating of water in closed chamber

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, water

I would like to be able to calculate the increase in pressure generated by heating a liquid in a closed chamber (no air gap, completely filled).  For example, I want to make sure that I don't exceed the pressure limit of 1.0 GPa when I heat the sample to 100 $^\circ$C.

I have a piece of equipment that allows me to fill the sample chamber (at room temperature) and apply load to generate a target pressure.  I would like to use this for some high pressure/temperature studies, but I need to ensure that I don't exceed the pressure limit (1.0 GPa) for the vessel.  This calculation would let me know what pressure I can apply at room temperature to stay within the safety limit when heating to 100 $^\circ$C.

Typically this is done with water systems, but I will also apply to other fluids such as ethanol/silicone oil etc.

Comment: The vapour pressure of water at $100^{\circ}\mathrm{C}$ is only $101325\mathrm{Pa}$, so well under your threshold. Consult a $PVT$ diagram of water.

Comment: Note that properties of materials change with temperature. If the MWP (maximum working pressure) is defined at room temperature, it is not appropriate to guess what it is at elevated (or depressed) temperatures. Consult your local pressure safety expert.

Comment: @Gert, the OP stated that his container is completely filled with liquid.  Vapor pressure doesn't apply in this case, but the rate of thermal expansion of the container vs. the rate of thermal expansion of water does apply.

Comment: Is there a specific question here? I don't see one, in which case the OP should edit their post with a specific question.

Comment: @Gert, Im not sure if the PVT phase diagram would help me.  If I pressurize the vessel and then heat the volume (in ideal world) shouldnt expand and so volume should remain fixed.  However, if I can use the PVT info to calculate the corresponding pressure increase please point me in the right direction.  Thanks